# How to apply conditional statment dependent on one column to another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with input data requires some formatting. In a section of this data that is 1,000 rows long, if the cat column is greater than 0 I need the kitten column to be 1. In a different 1,000 row part of the same data, if the cat column is less than 0, I need the kitten column to be 1. Otherwise the kitten column should be 0.

I have seen advice for replacing column and formulas for pandas dataframe objects but nothing I have seen in the documentation or the posts here covers how to apply a conditional function to a column.

I am also avoiding replacing the entire row sections in the data. I just want to apply this formula to one column.

Here's what I've tried. The obvious flaw with this is that it does not apply these changes to the entire dataframe.

```py
def kitten_column(dataframe, columnnumber):

    data1k, data3k = [], []

    data1k = dataframe.iloc[1000:2000,:]
    data3k = dataframe.iloc[3000:40000,:] 

    dataframe.insert(columnnumber, "kitten", 0, True)

    data1k.loc[data1k["cat"] < 0, "kitten"] = 1
    data3k.loc[data3k["cat"] > 0, "kitten"] = 1
```

My goal is to apply this to the original dataframe, without invoking an append or concatenate, but the code above will only apply it to the data1k and data3k dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dude arent you just looking for:

```
df.loc[(df["cat"] < 0) & (df.index > 1000) & (df.index < 2000), "kitten"] = 1
df.loc[(df["cat"] > 0) & (df.index > 3000) & (df.index < 40000), "kitten"] = 1
```